# how to correct rewrite nginx + apache urls

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

I have website (frontend - nginx, backend - (apache+php) ), this is nginx config file

```
server {

listen *:80;
server_name website.plus www.website.plus;
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
location / {
proxy_redirect          off;
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81/;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
proxy_connect_timeout 120;
proxy_send_timeout 120;
proxy_read_timeout 180;

}

}
```

apache

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:81>
        ServerName website.plus
        ServerAlias www.website.plus
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/website

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

and have this web urls

```
website.plus/tag.php?tag=cat
website.plus/search.php?search_content=cat
website.plus/view.php?image=LhUId4avpxVZK
```

please help me, how I can change (rewrite) urls to

```
website.plus/tag/cat
website.plus/search/cat
website.plus/view/LhUId4avpxVZK
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (untested):

```
rewrite ^tag.php?tag=(.*) tag/$1;
rewrite ^search.php?search_content=(.*) search/$1;
rewrite ^view.php?image=(.*) view/$1;
```

I think it's clear (with [documentation of nginx's rewrite](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite)) but if you have a question please ask!

Comment: Oh, sorry, I don't use apache... I can't help with apache... sorry :(